# Only first of several linkedin follow up buttons showing up in Firefox

Tags: firefox, linkedin-api

I've implemented several LinkedIn follow buttons in my web page. In all browser, all the buttons show up. However, in Firefox, only the first one shows up within a div with a width of 66px (this div's id is body), the others show up within a 2px width div, so you can only see a blue vertical stripe.

If it helps, here's the first body div

```
    <div id="body" style="width: 66px;">
```

and the rest of them:

```
    <div id="body" style="width: 2px;">
```

This is code generated by code provided by [LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company).

Comment: Can you give a link to the page with the problem?